# Searching for cable which links Senheiser headphone directly to computer over 3.5 mm jacket

Tags: headphones, audio-adapters

I have a Senheiser HD 559 which comes with a cable that has an 6.3 mm jack connection. Now I wanna connect this heaphone to a normal PC with a 3.5 mm female jacket. Unfortunately every (and with every I mean high quality brands product and cheap brand product) sell 6.3mm Female Plug to 3.5 mm Male Jack Stereo Adaptor, which always have a loose contact. So I wanna buy a cable that connects my heaphone and has a direct 3.5 mm male jacket which can be connected to any device directly.
[image: In the image you can see the cable that comes with the headset. I don't know how much mm the jacket has that goes into the headphones so I don't know what to search for.]

Comment: Are you simply looking for a 3.5mm to 3.5mm M-M lead?

Comment: No, I'm searching for a 2.5 mm to 3.5 mm M-M lead. I bought one cable for another similar headphone model from senheiser, but it's not here yet. I will see if it will fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what type of connector is on the other end, but my guess would be it's a 4-pin 2.5mm jack. Those are sometimes used for balanced headphone signal. The cables are not very common, but knowing what plug it is you should be able to find and order one.